# htaccess regex mandatory number after a string

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess regex

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap_(set|art|sub)_(([0-9]+)?).xml$ index.php?url=sitemap&doc=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NE,L]
```

**I need the "*" sign followed by some number to be optional. And the "*" sign alone cannot be present without having a number followed by that "_" sign.**

I have tried to make the "_" sign to be optional by including a ? at the end but still strings like sitemap_set_ gets matched.

*Hope my explanation is clear enough for you to help. else specify anything that looks confusing.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it like this:

```
RewriteRule ^sitemap_(set|art|sub)(?:_([0-9]+))?\.xml$ index.php?url=sitemap&doc=$1&id=$2 [QSA,NE,L]
```

This makes under followed by 1 or more digits optional.

Comment: the thing is I want underscore followed by a digit optional, however for the underscore to exist there should be a number followed. Eg: sitemap_set_ gets matched by the above answer. What I want to do is if the underscore exist it must have a digit at the end. Eg: sitemap_set_2

Comment: And that is exactly above regex is doing. It will match _ only if followed by numbers and whole match is optional.

Comment: sorry about that. your answer is working. earlier I checked your answer & looks like the changes were not replicated to the server folder from my source file.